# Adding a signature in pdf in powerapps

Tags: html, pdf, powerapps

i am trying to add a signature in a pdf in powerapps using the peninput field. i add the following in the html file which file is successfully converted in pdf through the flow

```
<img src='"& JSON(PenInput4.Image; JSONFormat.IgnoreBinaryData) &"' 
      style='width:80px;height:50px'></img>
```

but i see this in the pdf [a box with an x on the top left corner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjm59.png)

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The result of the JSON function already includes quotes, so you are "double-quoting" the image source. This is what you have:

```
<img src='"data:image/png;base64,..."' style='...'></img>
```

You can either use the double quotes (`"`) that are returned by the JSON function:

```
"<img src=" & JSON(PenInput4.Image; JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData) &
  " style='width:80px;height:50px'></img>"
```

Or you if you want to use single quotes (`'`) in your HTML document, you can keep your single quotes and remove the double quotes from the JSON output:

```
Set(penInputEncodedImage, JSON(PenInput4.Image; JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData));;
...
"<img src='" &
    Mid(penInputEncodedImage, 2, Len(penInputEncodedImage) - 2) &
    "' style='width:80px;height:50px'></img>"
```

Just a final note: you are using JSONFormat.**Ignore**BinaryData - the correct flag to be able to encode images should be JSONFormat.**Include**BinaryData. It seems to be working today, but that goes against the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-json) so it is a bug that may be fixed someday.

Comment: Thank you carlosfigueira, i removed the single quotes and used the includebinarydata, but the image doesn't appear the content of peninput, it appears only the background color.

Comment: everything is ok, i used the second example and everything works fine. thank you! do you know if i can convert the pen input in png format  and not in jpg?

Comment: I don't know if you can choose which format to use for the image - I believe it's dependent on the platform. What I've observed is that on the iOS app I get jpg, while on a browser I get png.